# Type Error: getElementById..null with h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: javascript, jsp

The code is working and setting the values  with

```
setCookie('newWindow', document.getElementById("myForm:header:"+1+":chekDeleted").checked? 1:0,100);
```

but when i call the getElementById in loop it says type error

```
var count = 0;

for(i=1;i<totalRecords;i++)
{
    var chkBox = getElementById("myForm:header:"+i+":chekDeleted");
    if(chkBox.checked == true)
    {
        count++;
        if(count > 1)
        {
            setCookie('newWindow', document.getElementById("myForm:header:"+i+":chekDeleted").checked? 1:0,100);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `getElementById` without referencing `document`, should be: `var chkBox = document.getElementById(...`. If this doesn't solve, sharing the error message would help.

Comment: it should not be `document.getElementById`?

Comment: are you sure your loop is not doing one time too many times?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] with a simple html page (only the component)  and this statement. Don't need the cookie since this is not relevant here. PS : the tag JSP is not usefull in a pure Javascript code. From what I can see, you have test this with `i = 1` only. Are you sure you have at least `totalRecords` element here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `document.`:

```
for(i=1;i<totalRecords;i++)
{
        var chkBox = document.getElementById("myForm:header:"+i+":chekDeleted");
    if(chkBox.checked == true)
    {
        count++;
        if(count > 1)
        {
            setCookie('newWindow', document.getElementById("myForm:header:"+i+":chekDeleted").checked? 1:0,100);

        }
    }
}
```

If you still having the error, it is because the element with those ids are not loaded. in that case, `chkBox` returns `null` and `if(chkBox.checked == true)` returns error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null**

Comment: i added the document.getElementById("myForm:header:"+i+":chekDeleted");

Comment: I think it is not problem because of the loop

Comment: If I do `console.log(document.getElementById("myForm:header:"+i+":chekDeleted"));` it is working

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: `code`<f:facet name="header">
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkDeletedAll" onclick="selectAllCheckBoxes(this.checked);"/>
          </f:facet>
                 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkDeleted" value="#{row.markedForDeletion}" onclick="eventClick1(this)"/>
               </h:column>`code`

Comment: But the id is `id="chkDeleted"`, not `'myForm:header:'+i+',...:che‌​kDeleted'`.

Comment: before the loop try this: `console.log(document.getElementById("myForm:header:1:che‌​kDeleted"))`, I am sure it will print `null` in the log

Comment: it is saying "false"

Comment: <f:facet name="header"> <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkDeletedAll" onclick="selectAllCheckBoxes(this.checked);"/> </f:facet> <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkDeleted" value="#{row.markedForDeletion}" onclick="eventClick1(this)"/> </h:column>